# MySQL WHERE IN subquery with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm creating a SQL query / subquery that will return a list of "class days". The query I'm using seems to not be recognizing the values from the subquery, and I cannot figure out why. If I run the subquery, I get the correct values. For some reason when I try to run the entire query & subquery together it doesn't work correctly, and I only get results for the 1st value in the comma separated list. If I run the query below, I only get results for tblclasses.cla_ID = 1234:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    classdays
WHERE
    classdays.classday_classid IN (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS(', ',
                        tclasses.cla_ID,
                        tclasses.cla_nextclass,
                        tclasses_1.cla_nextclass) AS nextclasses
        FROM
            tclasses
                LEFT JOIN
            tclasses AS tclasses_1 ON tclasses.cla_nextclass = tclasses_1.cla_ID
        WHERE
            tclasses.cla_ID = 1234)
```

However if I run just the subquery, it works and I get the list of values: 1234, 5678, 9012

```
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ',tclasses.cla_ID,tclasses.cla_nextclass,tclasses_1.cla_nextclass) AS nextclasses
   FROM
       tclasses
   LEFT JOIN
       tclasses AS tclasses_1 ON tclasses.cla_nextclass = tclasses_1.cla_ID
   WHERE
       tclasses.cla_ID = 1234)
```

And if I simply run the query with the values in the IN statement like so, it works as well:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    classdays
WHERE
    classdays.classday_classid IN (1234, 5678, 9012)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as for some reason I can't get the IN statement to run on those 3 comma separated values

Thanks!

Comment: `IN` doesn't work with comma-delimited strings. When you use `x IN (subquery)` it does an exact comparison to each row of the subquery result.

Comment: Instead of combining the columns with `CONCAT_WS`, put them in separate rows using `UNION`.

Comment: The 3 comma separated values are treated as a literal string `'value1, value2, value3'`.

Comment: @Barmar - I've never really used a UNION query before. I understand the basics of it, but since I'm essentially joining the same table on itself `LEFT JOIN tclasses AS tclasses_1 ON tclasses.cla_nextclass = tclasses_1.cla_ID` how would that UNION query look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can JOIN `classdays` with your subquery but without CONCAT_WS, and use an IN condition in the ON clause:

```
SELECT classdays.*
FROM classdays
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    tclasses.cla_ID,
    tclasses.cla_nextclass as next1,
    tclasses_1.cla_nextclass as next2
  FROM tclasses
  LEFT JOIN tclasses AS tclasses_1
    ON tclasses.cla_nextclass = tclasses_1.cla_ID
  WHERE tclasses.cla_ID = 1234
) c ON classdays.classday_classid IN (c.cla_ID, c.next1, c.next2)
```

You might need `SELECT DISTINCT classdays.*`, if the subquery can return more than one row, or wehen the list `c.cla_ID, c.next1, c.next2` can contain duplicates.

What Barmar mentioned with `UNION` would be

```
SELECT classdays.*
FROM classdays
WHERE classdays.classday_classid IN (
  SELECT tclasses.cla_ID
  FROM tclasses 
  WHERE tclasses.cla_ID = 1234

  UNION

  SELECT tclasses.cla_nextclass
  FROM tclasses
  WHERE tclasses.cla_ID = 1234

  UNION 

  SELECT tclasses_1.cla_nextclass
  FROM tclasses
  JOIN tclasses AS tclasses_1 ON tclasses.cla_nextclass = tclasses_1.cla_ID
  WHERE tclasses.cla_ID = 1234
)
```

Note that you don't need a JOIN for the first two UNION parts. And for last part you can use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically make an IN list from a string.

But you also don't need to, you can just join classdays.classday_classid to the set returned by the subquery.

Comment: Ok that makes sense about not being able to dynamically make an IN list from a string. Regarding joining in classdays.classday_classid to the set returned by the subquery, how do I do this since it's 3 separate columns returned, rather than 3 rows? I'm a beginner to SQL and stumped on this! The help is much appreciated